# Queueable logs don't have a completed date?

Tags: apex, queueable-interface, queueable-apex

Working on writing a queueable and noticed that the completed date field under Apex Jobs is blank. Futures have this. Is the only way I can get a run time is to log it myself?

Answer (score 0):

As of now (Spring 17), "Completion Date" is available for both the "Apex Jobs" page and "CompletedDate" of  AsyncApexJob record